# comparing template parameter to null

Tags: c++, templates, null

I have a method with a template parameter

```
bool insert_into_tree(const T new_key, const long &new_index){}
```

`T` is limited to `std::string` and `int` types.  I would like values of `new_key` to be meaningful and thus I do not want an empty `std::string` but can accept a zero value for `int`.

This is an example of a Java template comparison to null

```
if (key == null) {}

key defined as T extends Comparable<? super T>
```

Within c++

```
key is defined as template <class T>
```

If `T` is `std::string`, there is no `overloaded operator==` such that comparison to `NULL` is possible.

If `T` is `int`, comparison to null is acceptable.

Thus, what method could I employ to make the template parameter comparison work as in Java?

In other words, if in Java I have a template parameter I can compare to null, how could I compare a template parameter in c++ such that NULL or some other appropriate value indicating null could be achieved.

Comment: Semantically, what would you consider to be the "null" value of `bool`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Comparing `int` to `NULL` works, but probably not the way you think. It simply compares to `0` (since `NULL` is a macro for `0`). In the Java case, `key` is a pointer (which can thus be `null`). In your C++ case, you're working with a `key` object directly, so being `null` is not really defined there.

Comment: @NPE False as NULL is a #define equating to the numerical value 0

Comment: @mfontanini Reading comprehension ... `Thus, what method could I employ to make the template parameter comparison work as in Java?`

Comment: @Mushy OMG *how* didn't I see that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remember that this isn't Java, it's C++ and they work different ways. Possibly the most *similar* way to do this would be to create a `Comparable` template and ensure that both `key` and the classes you want to compare to instantiate it. So instead of using `std::string` you'd use `Comparable< std::string >` That's one way of doing it but *almost certainly not* the best way.

A better way overload the comparison operator to provide the comparisons that you want. That would allow you to be specific in your comparison. Watch out for implicit casting though.

Whichever way you chose will be largely based on the broader context of your code and without more information, it's hard to be specific about which method is best.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has no nullable types (all types in C++ are by default value-types, there is no reference-types, how in Java, so you cannot compare some type with some magic null). You can use pointers, or [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) here.

> If T is int, comparison to null is acceptable.

Yes, it's acceptable, since NULL in C++ is simply 0.